# How to calculate headcount in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have some problem with the HR Dashboard, where I can't get it to work properly.

I have the following visuals:

[Visual for HR Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmATz.png)

The headcount code is as follow:

```
Headcount = CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( FactTable[EmpID]),
    FILTER ( ALL(FactTable), FactTable[EmploymentStatus] = "Active" )
)
```

The problem is, that the visual doesn't slice on the `seniority`.

Need help.

Comment: Your `EmpID` is also unique or will duplicate one?

Comment: It is unique.
I have gotten the code to work by changing it to:
Headcount = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(FactTable),FILTER(ALL(FactTable),AND(FactTable[DateofHire] <= MIN('Kaldt funktion'[Date]),OR(FactTable[DateofTermination] = BLANK(),FactTable[DateofTermination] >= MAX('Kaldt funktion'[Date]))))).
The visual still shows the same value everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

First its bad maner to write code like this:

```
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( FactTable[EmpID] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( FactTable ),
        AND (
            FactTable[DateofHire] <= MIN ( 'Kaldt funktion'[Date] ),
            OR (
                FactTable[DateofTermination] = BLANK (),
                FactTable[DateofTermination] >= MAX ( 'Kaldt funktion'[Date] )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

A good practice is to use ALL with columns that you really need in your filter. Second instead of comparing column = BLANK() use function ISBLANK(Table[ColumnName]). You also should compare SELECTEDVALUE to get the correct data. (unfortunately, you don't post any samples, and I don't know how your data looks like I can only guess). How is correlated 'Kaldt funktion' with FactTable? Probably problem is in your MIN and MAX. We can also use && insted of AND, and || insted of OR;

```
CALCULATE (
DISTINCTCOUNT ( FactTable[EmpID] ),
FILTER (
    ALL ( FactTable[DateofHire], FactTable[DateofTermination] ),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( FactTable[DateofHire] ) <= MIN ( 'Kaldt funktion'[Date] )
        && (
            ISBLANK ( FactTable[DateofTermination] )
                || SELECTEDVALUE ( FactTable[DateofTermination] ) >= MAX ( 'Kaldt funktion'[Date] )
        )
)
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I have try with some sample data, i guess the issue here is due to you are using `filter` function, you can try my method if the problem can be solved:

1)I have this original sample table

[image]

2. I have created a measure to count the total employee still with company

   `Total count = CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet1[ID]),Sheet1[Status] = "active")`

3)My `scorecard` has displayed the `total count` correct for with junior `slicer`

[image]

Comment: Hello Kin, thank you so much for your answer.
The problem is, that i am slicing on the "hiringdate", then i want the visual to slice on the "seniority, like in the above picture.
I am currently using this line of code to make sure, that i have headcount for alle the years from my selection year and back and not just the year i have chosen:
Headcount = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(FactTable[EmpID]),FILTER(ALL(FactTable),AND(FactTable[DateofHire] <= MIN('Kaldt funktion'[Date]),OR(FactTable[DateofTermination] = BLANK(),FactTable[DateofTermination] >= MAX('Kaldt funktion'[Date])))))

Comment: Why you are using `AND` `OR` within a single function, won't it confuse the system? It is hard to tell what is the problem here..